# How to rank for keywords in Google?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-hosting

This might be a silly question, but seeing as I am new to actually putting websites online it has become an important one.

When trying to rank for keywords in google, do I need any special code? I know you can place a meta-tag but I have heard that it is not as useful as it once was.

If i just place my keywords (that i want to rank for) in regular p-tags and h-tags for example, does google see them and rank me for them?

Comment: i don't know if this question is truly answerable. google publishes [some guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769) that clue us into what practices they may reward and punish when crawling and ranking websites. but the actual implementations are a trade secret, and there's no way to give a definitive answer.

Comment: This question is kind of general, you need to ask a specific question and support it with codes, snapshots etc

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your markup in a semantic way, i.e. a `<h1>` tag for your main heading which should be one of the first things on the page,  tags for sub headings, etc.

You should use `<p>` tags for paragraphs, `<ul>` and `<li>` for list items, etc.  Always think about the most appropriate tags to use. For example, should that client testimonial go in a regular `<p>` tag or would be it better in a `<blockquote>` tag.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

The `<title>` tag which goes in the document `<head>` is important since this explains very briefly what the page is about, and shows up as the blue link in Google.  Likewise the `meta-description` tag gives you an opportunity to influence the description that people see in the search results.  Without this, Google will just pick some random content from your page, which might not be as attractive for potential visitors to click on.  So whilst the meta-description might not help your ranking as such, it can help to convert more impressions into actual clicks.

If you are displaying information about an organization, a product, list of products, reviews, etc then you can consider adding additional markup known as Structured Data (RDFa, Microdata and JSON-LD) which better helps to describe the information that you're displaying and allows Google to make better sense of it.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

http://schema.org/